# Group ListView by a component on a JSON in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to group items from a JSON in the ListView.

My JSON is stored in an web repository, I already pulled it from the server and listed it but ungrouped.

I've read a lot of tutorials about how to group C# List but none of them solved my problem.

Here's the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "status": "Status 1",
    "erpCode": "1901",
    "name": "Name 1",
    "statusReportDate": "24/08/2018",
    "statusReportDescription": "Description 1"
  },
  {
    "status": "Status 2",
    "erpCode": "2160",
    "name": "Name 2",
    "statusReportDate": "24/08/2018",
    "statusReportDescription": "Description 2"
  },
  {
    "status": "Status 2",
    "erpCode": "543",
    "name": "Name 3",
    "statusReportDate": "24/08/2018",
    "statusReportDescription": "Description 3"
  }
]
```

My method that pull the JSON from a web repository and convert it to a List and ObservableCollection:

```
protected async void OnGetList()
{
    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {

        try
        {
            //Getting JSON data from the Web
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);

            //We deserialize the JSON data from this line
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Company>>(content);

            //After deserializing , we store our data in the List called ObservableCollection
            ObservableCollection<Company> collection = new ObservableCollection<Company>(list);
            myList.ItemsSource = collection;

        }
        catch (Exception ey)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("" + ey);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True" 
                  ItemSelected="MyList_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                    <Button Text="{Binding erpCode}"/>

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding statusReportDate}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Label Text="{Binding statusReportDescription}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to group it by "status" and print something like this:

**Status 1**

Name 1

**Status 2**

Name 2

Name 3

**Status N**

Name n1

Name n2

Name n3

...

Comment: "none of them solved my problem" - why not?  What specifically did you try that didn't work?  Grouped ListViews are very well documented here on SO and elsewhere on the web.

Comment: I don't see any 'grouping operation' attempt in your code.

Comment: Something like `ObservableCollection<Company> collection = new ObservableCollection<Company>(list).GroupBy(x => x.status);` should get you started.

Comment: Jason, the documentation I read just tell me how to manually create grouped Lists, inserting all data on the code, none getting raw data from another list like a JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/

But better to use `ObservableCollection`, where the above article uses `List`.

So you have to create an ObservableCollection of a type that is a subclass of `ObservableCollection`.

First create a type that subclasses `ObservableCollection` that will hold one group of companies by status:

```
public class CompanyByStatusList : ObservableCollection<Company>
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Company> Companies => this;
}
```

Then create an `ObservableCollection` of `CompanyByStatusList`. This will be your ItemsSource for your `ListView`.

```
public ObservableCollection<CompanyByStatusList> CompanyList { get; set; }
```

Then you want to create a `CompanyByStatusList` for each status that holds all of the companies in that specific status, and then add each of those `CompanyByStatusList` to the `CompanyList` collection. Make sure to set the `Status` property of each `CompanyByStatusList`

And make sure to set `IsGroupingEnabled="true"` on your `ListView`. ListView xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyList}"
      IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
         HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Status}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                    <Button Text="{Binding erpCode}"/>

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding statusReportDate}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding statusReportDescription}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```