# Xamarin Custom ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin

Im getting data from API. My List View shows all the matches sorted by hours, for example

```
 20:00 Manchester City v .... 
 20:00 Ajax v ....
 21:00 Shakhtar. v ....
```

I want to make a listView like below;

**Champions League - Group E**

20:00 Ajax   v  Bayern München
20:00 Benfica v AEK Atina

**Champions League  - Grup F**

20:00  Manchester City v   Hoffenheim
 21:00  Shakhtar Donetsk  v Lyon
 21:00  .....    v  .....

How can I make my ListView looks like this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question here: [Group ListView by a component on a JSON in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563916/group-listview-by-a-component-on-a-json-in-xamarin-forms/53565958#53565958)

I will mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: thanks a lot jgoldberger. I want upvote your answer but i have 14 reputation point. It should be 15 at least...